# How to find 90th% value?

Tags: groovy

I have this list:

```
def grades = [5,4,3,2,1,1]
```

Where index is a grade, and value is an occurrence of the grade:

| Grade | Occurrence |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |

How can I calculate the 90th percentile for the grades?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate percentile from a long array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413544/calculate-percentile-from-a-long-array)

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, a total of 16 grades have been given (5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 16). 90 % are 14.4 grades, so discard the lowest 14 grades and take the smallest remaining (in your example it will be 4).

How to code? There are some ways:

1. You may count through the array you have got. Subtract 5 from 14 (= 9), then 4, then 3, then 2. Once you reach zero, you’re at the index of the 90th percentile.
2. Maybe easier to understand, but will require a few more code lines: Put all 16 grades into an array (or list): [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]. Since the array is sorted, the median is found at index 14.

I believe you will learn the most from coding it yourself, so I am not taking that pleasure or learning away from you.

Answer (score 0):

This gets me a whole grade. I was hoping to find an exact value of 90th percentile, but this will do for me.

```
def grades = [5,4,3,2,1,1]

sum=grades.sum()

per_grade=0
per_value=sum*0.9
 grades.eachWithIndex { grade_count, grade ->
  per_value-=grade_count
   if (per_value<0){per_grade=grade-1}
   if (per_value==0){per_grade=grade}
 }
out.write(per_grade)
```